# How to open a file in netbeans project without defining the path

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a method to open a file in NetBeans but I would to open this file from within project without defining the path is this possible. Below is the code I have at the moment where i open the file but I define the path first there is also a screenshot of the file in the project

```
private void jMenu2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "C:\\Users\\kevin\\Documents\\Uni\\SSIS\\src\\SSISPackage\\helpfile.txt");
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use System.getProperty("user.dir"):
//which gives your project path

Comment: should it be like this?


 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + System.getProperty("user.helpfile.txt"));

Comment: try { Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " +  System.getProperty("user.dir"):+"//helpfile.txt");